# Parsing natural text to array

Tags: java, string, parsing

How can I parse natural strings like these:

`"10 meters"`
`"55m"`

Into instances of this class:

```
public class Units {
    public String name; //will be "meters"
    public int howMuch; //will be 10 or 55
}
```

P.S. I want to do this with NLP libraries, I'm really a noob in NLP and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this ? Sounds nasty

Comment: is there anything else you need to parse, or only 'number' + 'meters'? and why do you need the array to be of that format, is it obligatory?

Comment: Turning natural language into computer representations with units and what-not is pretty complicated. Find a library to do it for you.

Comment: your expectation looks incoherent to me... I would expected ans answer 10 meters AND 55 meters too, OR 10m and 55m...

Comment: @ifly6 really ? If it's just about simple formats like this, this can be achieved pretty easily. If it gets richer, yep that becomes difficult but I don't think that's the case for the OP

Comment: @ifly6, there's one problem: I can't got, how to work with these libraries, because I can't found any documentation for them in my language

Comment: @Dici, there will be other expressions, but for now I need to make at least this working.

Comment: @krzyk I tried NLP libraries, but I can't got what actually I need to do.

Comment: @NeoKat you don't specify your question well, which is why you still did not get any good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following algorithm:

1. Separate the text into words by looping through each character and breaking off a new word each time you encounter a space: this can be stored in a String array. Make sure that each word is stored lowercase.
2. Store a 2-dimensional String array as a database of all the units you want to recognize: this could be done with each sub-array representing one unit and all its equivalent representations: for example, the sub-array for meters might look like {"meter","meters","m"}.
3. Make two parallel ArrayLists: the first representing all numerical values and the second representing their corresponding units.
4. Loop through the list of words from step 1: for each word, check if it is in the format nubmer+unit (without an adjoining space). If so, then split the number off and put it in the first ArrayList. Then, find the unabbreviated unit corresponding with the abbreviated unit given in the text by referring to the 2-dimensional string array (this should be the first index of the subarray). Add this unit to the second ArrayList. Finally, if the word is a single number,  check if the next word corresponds with any of the units; if it does, then find its unabbreviated unit (the first index of the sub-array). Then add the number and its unit to their respective ArrayLists.

Comment: But, what if string will be in 2 words ? Like "20 meters". Isn't better to use RegExp ?

Comment: This will still be able to process strings like that

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but I recommend you don't do this. An array usually holds only hold one type of data structures, so it cannot hold an int and a string at the same time. If you did do it, you would have to do `Object[][]`

Comment: Sure you can, it's just an array of objects, i.e. `Object[][]`. Not nice, not recommended, but possible

Comment: I mean LIKE this, it can be my class, or something other, I need exactly parsing solution